# Aborted (стек памяти сброшен на диск)

Tags: c, массивы, память, динамические-массивы, сегментация

В чем проблема?

```
// функция для удаления элемента массива
int remove_element(double *array, int *n, int pos)
{
        if (pos >= *n || pos < 0)
        {
                printf("Incorrect position\n");

                return ERROR_POSITION;
        }

        double *tmp = (double*)calloc(*n, sizeof(double));


        if (!pos)
                for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
                        tmp[i-1] = array[i];
        else
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
                        tmp[i] = array[i];
                for (int i = pos; i < *n; i++)
                        tmp[i-1] = array[i];
        }

        free(array);

        (*n)--;

        array = (double*)malloc(*n * sizeof(double));

        for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++)
                array[i] = tmp[i];

        free(tmp);


        return SUCCESS;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, хотя бы

```
for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
    tmp[i-1] = array[i];
```

К какому элементу `tmp` будет обращение при первой итерации цикла?

Ну и еще мы же не знаем, что вы передаете как аргументы. Может, `array` у вас вовсе даже не динамически выделенный массив? Кстати, если даже динамически выделенный - то все равно у вас утечка памяти: вы же выделяете новую память, а указатель на нее благополучно теряете... А если по выходу из функции обратитесь по адресу `array` - будут неприятности: память-то уже освобождена.